# Adding a string to the end of a number in a file using awk?

Tags: awk

This is what I've tried and it returns an error. The number is in the second column

```
awk '$2 `{`gsub(/$2, "$2-000); print;`}`' ./file.txt
```

as

> "run away regular expression"

Comment: Welcome to SO,  Good that you posted your efforts in post, keep it up. It is always advisable to add samples of input and output in code tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's with the bunch of incorrect back-quotes? It is an incorrect syntax in your `awk` code. All you need to do is

```
awk '{ $2=$2"-000" }1' file.txt
```

The part `$2=$2"-000"` appends the string to `$2` and `1` at the end re-constructs the line with the modifications made, so that you don't have to do a `print` explicitly.

Comment: I found the back-quotes on this site in a similar question and thought it would apply to my situation.  That works perfectly!  You are a tremendous help, Inian!